# Writing html extension that accept list of Lambda expressions for accessing Properties

Tags: c#, razor

I want to write a html extension that generate HTML table;

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayPropreties<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, params Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>[] expressions)
    {
        // some code here
    }
}
```

The problem is when I want to call the method from the view:

```
@Html.DisplayPropreties(model => m.Id, model => m.Property1, model => m.Property2)
```

Im getting error:

> The type argument for method
>   'HtmlHelpers.DisplayPropreties(HtmlHelper, params
>   Expression>[])' cannot be inferred with
>   current usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

I did not touch c# for some while (3+y), and I don't fully understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what the error says.  You need to specify the type arguments as they can't be inferred, e.g.:

```
HtmlHelpers.GenerateTable<Foo, Bar>(model => m.Id, model => m.Property1, model => m.Property2);
```

Comment: Can you please explain me this a bit;
Foo is Type of model, and Bar is type of proprety (m.Id)?
If that's the case, I dont think it will work, because Property can be any type (String, Number, DateTime etc)

Comment: After doing that Im getting: Cannot convert method group 'DisplayPropreties' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Demo Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8OwH0O)

you can use `Json.Net`'s Jsonconvert Serialize collection obeject  then

DeserializeObject collection to DataTable then

call ConvertDataTableToHTML method get HtmlTable from the DataTable object.

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static string ToHtmlTable(this HashSet<dynamic> obj)
    {
        return ToHtmlTableConverter(obj);
    }

    public static string ToHtmlTable(this ICollection obj) {
        return ToHtmlTableConverter(obj);
    }

    public static string ToHtmlTable(this System.Data.DataTable obj)
    {
        return ConvertDataTableToHTML(obj);
    }

    private static string ToHtmlTableConverter( object obj  )  
    {
        var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(jsonStr);
        var html = ConvertDataTableToHTML(data);
        return html;
    }

    private static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(System.Data.DataTable dt)
    {
        var html = new StringBuilder("<table>");

        //header
        html.Append("<thead><tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            html.Append("<th>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>");
        html.Append("</tr></thead>");

        //body
        html.Append("<tbody>");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                html.Append("<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>");
            html.Append( "</tr>");
        }

        html.Append("</tbody>");
        html.Append("</table>");
        return html.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer!
What I want is to display some of object properties.
I would like that my call be something like this:
@Html.DisplayPropreties(model => m.Id, model => m.Property1, model => m.Property2)
The result should be table with 2 columns, and 3 rows; First row is proprety name second is value; With your solution I need to create additional class or add aditional property attribute; To keep it short, I don't wan to add additional classes I just want to show variable number of object properties to the view :)
With your solution I need to create array with property name/value

Comment: let me think ... @Darkves